# Move subscribers between lists with perceptive mcapi

Tags: move, mailchimp, mcapi

I am developing a integration between asp.net and mailchimp, using perceptive i did all code, create new campaigns, add subscribers,etc. Now i need some help to move subscribers between lists. I didn't find in perceptive documentation this question, someone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I stop using [Perceptive Mailchimp API](http://perceptivemcapi.codeplex.com/releases/view/57007) because if you can see the latest update was made in Mar 11, 2011... that's a long time ago and that means no more support and no more updates as Mailchimp is now in **version 2.0**.

I started using [MailChimp.NET](https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET) (supports MC API 2.0) where an updated was made **4 days ago**... very different no?

That said, to move/copy a subscriber to new/different list using the [Mailchimp API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/) you would use [List > Subscribe](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php) and [List > Unsubscribe](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/unsubscribe.php) if you want to remove the user from a list.

let's see the Subscribe

```
subscribe(string apikey, 
          string id,                 // the list id
          struct email,              // a struct with one of the following keys (email, euid, leid)
          struct merge_vars,         // optional merges for the email (FNAME, LNAME, etc.)
          string email_type,         // optional email type preference for the email (html or text - defaults to html)
            bool double_optin,       // optional flag to control whether a double opt-in confirmation message is sent, defaults to true
            bool update_existing,    // optional flag to control whether existing subscribers should be updated instead of throwing an error, defaults to false
            bool replace_interests,  // optional flag to determine whether we replace the interest groups with the groups provided or we add the provided groups to the member's interest groups (optional, defaults to true)
            bool send_welcome)       // optional if your double_optin is false and this is true --> this will *not* fire if we end up updating an existing subscriber
```

Now that you know how to do it in the official Mailchimp, it is probably easy to translate it to your own .NET wrapper.

as long as you have `update_existing` set to `true`, the welcome email will never fire up as you can read from the docs, and this way you can update a subscriber email and move him to any existing list.